# Error in Jenkins deployment :: [cargo.remote.username] [cargo.remote.password] properties are mandatory

Tags: jenkins

I am amused to see this error suddenly appearing in a jenkins deployment jobs which was working more than few months. While I didn't change any tomcat configuration and the setup needed to build and move a war file

like tomcat-user setup was done long back and didnt see any issue there.

What could be the reason. If someone can provide insight.

```
20:52:11 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
20:52:11 org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: The [cargo.remote.username] and [cargo.remote.password] properties are mandatory and need to be defined in your configuration.
20:52:11    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.createManager(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:318)
20:52:11    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.getTomcatManager(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:83)
20:52:11    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
20:52:11    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its my bad that I didn't see the configuration [username/password] in jenkins' for "Deploy war/ear to container" is muted.

[Below image displays what has been missed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvsDe.jpg)

After setting correct username and password It is resolved.

Where to look for password:->
Path :- /apache-tomcat-7.0.39/conf/tomcat-users.xml
Below line allows tomcatuser to depploy war file in webapps directory.

If this is not present in tomcat-users.xml then add one here, and verify if in unix/windows the user has proper access for file system of tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

If still have same issue ,please check Credentials key settings in 
Jenkins -> Configure Credentials -update Type select 
Jenkins credential provider

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. add manager user in tomcat , if you already configured that ok , copy and save in notepad .
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBVno.png)

2. in Jenkins , in post build
   add tomcat version and
   in credential select Jenkins add/paste the tomcat username and password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYED1.png)

here you need to select
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM3tc.png)

then save it now try to Build now
it think it will works !